# Google scripts adding to date function not working

Tags: javascript, scripting

I am trying to write a function, which when called, will add a day to a date if run at a certain time. When run at or before 4AM it will not change the date, whereas if run after 4AM it will add a day to the date. Please find my code below:

```js
function addOne() {
  var date = new Date();
  var tomorrow = new Date ();
  tomorrow.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
}

function deliverDate() {
  var date = new Date();
  var currentTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  var time = currentTime.toString()
  var hour = time.slice(0,2)
  Logger.log(hour)
  if (hour > "4") {var accurateDate = addOne();}
  else if (hour <= "4"){var accurateDate = date;}
  Logger.log(accurateDate)
}
```

I know, that the addOne function works, and the hour calculated is accurate. However running it at 12:48 yields the following log:

[21-01-04 12:48:55:468 GMT] 12
[21-01-04 12:48:55:470 GMT] Mon Jan 04 12:48:55 GMT+00:00 2021

I am fairly new to scripts, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, sorted this myself. If anyone is interested, all it was was adding zeros in the boolean statements.

```js
function addOne() {
  var date = new Date();
  var tomorrow = new Date ();
  tomorrow.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
}

function deliverDate() {
  var date = new Date();
  var currentTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  var time = currentTime.toString()
  var hour = time.slice(0,2)
  Logger.log(hour)
  if (hour > "04") {var accurateDate = addOne();}
  else if (hour <= "04"){var accurateDate = date;}
  Logger.log(accurateDate)
}
```